# Linear regression: an input variable as a multiplication/addition of other input variables

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression, python, linear-model

We have ways to identify collinearity in a multiple regression (using input variables' correlation matrix) and remove collinearity by dropping some of the collinear input variables.

But what can be done (apart from using the domain knowledge) to know if one input variable is a function (for simplicity let's say basic math operations +-*/) of other variables? Let's say `x3 = x1 * x2`.
I have such a case in my model, which is known to me, being aware of the relationships between the input variables. The questions are:

1. Is there any ways to identify such relationships systematically? There might be other hidden patterns too.
2. What is the effect of having such a relationship in a linear model?

To answer the 2nd question, I use a simple example:
our model could be `y = ax1 + bx2 + cx3 + d`. If `x3 = x1 + x2`, the model is equivalent to `y = (a+c)x1 + (b+c)x2 + d`. Now, this does not change the model, but in principle, this is similar to collinearity, it changes the interpretation of the effect of input variables. If there is a systematic way to detect such relationships (e.g. running a test), then we might be able to drop the variable with redundant information.

Comment: These sort of relationships would be called interactions and I think there is considerable literature on this. Further, the equivalence that you show would hold if `x3 = x1 + x2` and not for `x3 = x1*x2`.

Comment: @asifzuba, thanks for your comment. Yes, I realised that and have updated my question (my initial question was about basic math operations on the input variables +-*/). In the case of an "interaction", I have seen that people use `PolynomialFeatures` in python. So, would it be okay to just add the interaction to the linear model and have other items too? in this case, `y = ax1 + bx2 + cx3 + d` where `x3 = x1 *x2`?

Comment: yes, but please be mindful of the [sample size requirements](https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2018/03/15/need-16-times-sample-size-estimate-interaction-estimate-main-effect/) for testing for interactions

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood that post entirely, but I'm using all of my data and 80/20 training/test formula. actually, the interaction is highly correlated with the output variable, so I'd assume the model should be fine?

Comment: If using linear models you can also consider using a model comparison criteria like AIC/BIC. Fit the model with all the data with and without the interaction term. See how much improvement there is based on the AIC/BIC criteria. If your main effects are correlated with outcome, then it shouldn't be a surprise that the interaction term is also correlated, but you need to see how much it actually *helps* the model. HTH.